# Ubuntu 18.04 packages are giving timeouts

Tags: ubuntu, apt

since some hours ago, all ours Ubuntu-18.04 based github actions have started failing with the following errors:

```
After this operation, 348 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python3-pyparsing all 2.2.0+dfsg1-2 [52.2 kB]
Err:2 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 python3-packaging all 17.1-1
  Connection failed [IP: 52.252.75.106 80]
Fetched 52.2 kB in 1min 34s (555 B/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-packaging/python3-packaging_17.1-1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 52.252.75.106 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

It seems is always the `52.252.75.106` server that gives the timeout. Sometimes it seems to work though. Is there any way to fix this? Is this something temporal? Can I specify the OS to use another archive server? We are just a running an `apt-get install` command (that has not been modified in quite a long time).

Note: we have also noticed the install step now takes way longer than yesterday (around 10 times more).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to fix this? Is this something temporal?

It's not your mirror, so you can only hope it gets better.

> Can I specify the OS to use another archive server?

Sure. Choose a fast and trustworthy mirror in your vicinity hosting your release from the list of [Official Archive Mirrors for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) or pick one from [mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt](http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt) which should do the job for you (see related answer [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/a/37754) on askubuntu).

I'd probably comment out the Azure mirror and switch back to it later when the connection is more stable.